# How to check if only one Role is matching?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, membership

I need to filter users by Roles, but all users belong to two Roles

Example: `Admin` and `Group1` for one user, and `User` and `Group1` for the other.

Now I want to filter them by `Group1` Role and ignore `Admin` and `User`.

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
    var group = string.Join(" ", roles ); 
    group = group.Replace("Admin", "");//Used this to single out Group1 from Admin user
    return View(new UserViewModel
                    {
                        Users = _userService.FindAll().Where(x => Roles.GetRolesForUser(x.UserName).Contains(group)),
                        Roles = roles
                    });
}
```

This doesn't error out but it shows it empty. I think I know why but still can't figure out how to go around it...

Comment: Roles.GetRolesForUser(x.UserName) - What type does this return?

Comment: `string[]` Sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: It looks like a compile error, Contains on an array does not take an array as its parameter!

Comment: There are no errors at all... MY BAD~!!!  Updating Question!!!

Comment: Updated question, in desperation I forgot that I've did this...

Comment: If no one answers by the time I get home from work I will share the code I use to do exactly this.

Comment: Why it failed, is probably because of stray leading / trailing spaces after the replace!

Comment: I just corrected the string and excluded space as a joiner, so it shouldn't have any excess leading/trailing spaces, still the same :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
   var roleFilter = Roles.GetRolesForUser().First(r => !r.equals("Admin"));

   return View(new UserViewModel
                {
                    Users = _userService.FindAll().Where(x => Roles.GetRolesForUser(x.UserName).Contains(roleFilter)),
                    Roles = new [] {roleFilter}
                });
}
```

Comment: I know that will work. But I need to have that `OtherGroup`, aka. `Group1` in example as dynamic, because it will not be the same every time.

Comment: What is the logic to decide the role filter? Are you going to pass it in to your index action method on post?

Comment: Errm.. It's not much of a "logic" but take a look at the question, you'll see the messing with strings at start of the method, that should be "role filter" although I'm embarrassed to call it that >_>

Comment: Yes, but do you always to filter out admin from the roles list? Do you want to hardcode it? I am exactly sure how to want to decide filter at runtime

Comment: Yes I'm always removing `Admin` because that's a page that only `Admin` Role can come to, so it's always them. What do you mean exactly by hardcode it?

Comment: What happens in case user has User and Group1 role? Even if we filter by admin, we will have 2 roles for the user. Which one gets priority? You need to specific more business logic. What is the criteria for role filtering? Do you enter it on a text box in front end ?

Comment: Ok. You're misunderstanding. User that is initiating the method is ALWAYS `Admin` and `AnotherRole`, and users that need to be filtered are (proxy code) `All_Users.Where(RoleIsEqualTo("AnotherRole"))` So the `Admin` that's accessing/initiating the method will get the list of users that share that `AnotherRole` he has. Hope that this clarifies it a bit.
Also, I'm not entering it anywhere, it's already set. `Admin` was added to both roles on Registering, and he then created users that have `User` role and `AnotherRole`.

Comment: Just updated the answer. Does that look more like what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, here it goes. My understanding of your problem is that you want to check if the user has one or more specific roles. If so, allow access; otherwise, deny them access and send them into a black hole. It sounds like in your example that you want to only check one specific role. Reading some of your comments you may also want to check multiple roles at some point. The code example I will show you allows you to check a user against a set of one or more roles that the user must be assigned to in order to gain access to the page.

```
string[] requiredRoles = new string[] { "Awesome", "Pancake" };
if (requiredRoles.Except(theUsersAssignedRoles).Any())
{
    // Authorization has failed!
    // The user is not awesome and they are not a pancake.
}
else
{
    // User is awesome and a pancake so let them through.
}
```

The idea here is to take a list of all required roles and subtract out all of the roles the user has assigned to him or her. If there are any roles left in the list after the subtraction, then the user doesn't have all of the required roles. Here are a few examples. The roles that are required for authorization are on the left of the subtraction sign while the user's assigned roles are on the right of the subtraction sign just like the above code.

User is awesome and a pancake so they are allowed access. Notice we end up with an empty set which means the user meets the requirements:

```
{ "Awesome", "Pancake" } - { "Awesome", "Pancake" } = { }
```

User is only a pancake. They are not allowed access. The resulting set contains "Awesome" so that means they are missing the "Awesome" role:

```
{ "Awesome", "Pancake" } - { "Pancake" } = { "Awesome" }
```

This user is not awesome or a pancake but she is an admin. Still, we require awesome pancakes in order to enter the page so this user is denied access:

```
{ "Awesome", "Pancake" } - { "Admin" } = { "Awesome", "Pancake" }
```

If you have any questions or this isn't what you want, please leave a comment. I'll be happy to help you out further if needed.

Comment: Sorry, different time-zones, I was sleeping. Will try that.

Comment: OK! tranceporters solution was exactly what I needed, but yours (unknowingly) solved my other problem with different part of application! So + and THANKS!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

It really sounds like you're trying to use this method instead:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.getusersinrole.aspx
>
> Parameters
>
> `roleName`
> Type: System.String
> The name of the role to get the list of users for.

Comment: Hmmmm, there's a strong possibility you are correct... To be honest I'm so confused right now, I don't even know how to try this :D